# index in oracle, clustered or unclustered

Tags: oracle, indexing, clustered-index

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is an index clustered or unclustered in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290422/is-an-index-clustered-or-unclustered-in-oracle)

i've a table with 3 imported key, there's an index for each of them, how can i verifity the type of index? If is it a clustered index (so the data pointed by index are ordered) or unclestered?
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle does not have a "clustered index" (at least not the way this term is used e.g. in SQL Server)

The closest thing to a clustered index is an index organized table in Oracle.